# Correctly measuring constituent fundamental operations in sorting

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, stl

I am trying to add some telemetry to the sorting functions in the standard library. I want to count the number of swaps, moves (including the ones invoked by the swap), and comparisons operations in the `std::sort()` and `std::stable_sort()` functions.

In order to do so, I am taking the following steps:

1. Create a struct to encapsulate the counts of the operations I want to measure
2. Create a wrapper for the comparison function object to increment the comparison count
3. Specialize the `std::swap()` function and increment the swap count
4. Create a custom move function and invoke that from the specialized std::swap() function created in step #3
5. Finally, run `std::sort()` and `std::stable_sort()` and gather stats

I get the following output, which may be correct because the `std::stable_sort()` is not likely to invoke any swaps:

```
std::sort(): Moves: 68691, Swaps: 22897, Comparisons: 156959
std::stable_sort(): Moves: 0, Swaps: 0, Comparisons: 183710
```

However, if I replace #4 step above with this:

- Specialize the `std::move()` function and increment the move count

The output has 0 moves for `std::sort()`, which is definitely not right:

```
std::sort(): Moves: 0, Swaps: 22897, Comparisons: 156959
std::stable_sort(): Moves: 0, Swaps: 0, Comparisons: 183710
```

Furthermore, my compiler's (LLVM 8.1.0 on Darwin 16.5.0) implementation of `std::stable_sort()` is ridden with move() calls. So, I am also expecting non-zero move count in the output.

Please take a look at my code below (MVCE for the first case followed by the excerpt for the second/broken case) and see if you can answer these questions:

1. **Is my overall approach for stats collection reasonable?**
2. **Why is the second case broken and how may I fix it?**
3. **Is there a way to simplify (make less verbose) the wrapper for the comparison functor, at least the std::ref() part?**

Base code (for the first case):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>
#include<cassert>
#include<numeric>
#include<algorithm>

namespace test {

// struct to store the count of swaps, moves, and comparisons
struct sort_stats {
    long long int __count_swaps;
    long long int __count_moves;
    long long int __count_comps;

    void reset_stats() { __count_swaps = 0; __count_moves = 0; __count_comps = 0; }

    void incr_count_swaps() { ++__count_swaps; }
    void incr_count_moves() { ++__count_moves; }
    void incr_count_comps() { ++__count_comps; }

    std::string to_str() {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Moves: " << __count_moves
           << ", Swaps: " << __count_swaps
           << ", Comparisons: " << __count_comps;
        return ss.str();
    }
};

// static instance of stats
static sort_stats __sort_stats;

// my custom move template
template<class T>
inline
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&
move(T&& x) noexcept
{
    test::__sort_stats.incr_count_moves();
    return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(x);
}

// Wrapper for comparison functor
template <class _Comp>
class _WrapperComp
{
    public:
    typedef typename _Comp::result_type result_type;
    typedef typename _Comp::first_argument_type arg_type;

    _WrapperComp(_Comp comp) : __comp(comp) { }
    result_type operator()(const arg_type& __x, const arg_type& __y)
    {
        test::__sort_stats.incr_count_comps();
        return __comp(__x, __y);
    }

    private:
    _Comp __comp;
};
}

// Specialization of std::swap (for int type)
namespace std {
template<>
inline
void
swap<int>(int& a, int&b) noexcept(is_nothrow_move_constructible<int>::value
                                  && is_nothrow_move_assignable<int>::value)
{
    test::__sort_stats.incr_count_swaps();
    using test::move;
    int temp(move(a));
    a = move(b);
    b = move(temp);
}
}

using namespace test;

int main()
{
    const size_t SIZE = 10000;
    auto v = std::vector<int>(SIZE);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);

    auto wrapper_less = _WrapperComp<std::less<int>>(std::less<int>());
    auto ref_wrapper_less = std::ref(wrapper_less);

    // Run std::sort() and gather stats
    std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << "std::sort(): ";
    __sort_stats.reset_stats();
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), ref_wrapper_less);
    assert(std::is_sorted(v.begin(), v.end()));
    std::cout << __sort_stats.to_str() << "\n";

    // Run std::stable_sort() and gather stats    
    std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << "std::stable_sort(): ";
    __sort_stats.reset_stats();
    std::stable_sort(v.begin(), v.end(), ref_wrapper_less);
    assert(std::is_sorted(v.begin(), v.end()));
    std::cout << __sort_stats.to_str() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the diff excerpt for the second case:

```
namespace std {
// Add specialization for std::move()
template<>
inline
std::remove_reference<int>::type&&
move<int>(int&& x) noexcept
{
    test::__sort_stats.incr_count_moves();
    return static_cast<std::remove_reference<int>::type&&>(x);
}

// Invoke std::move() instead of test::move from the specialized std::swap() function
template<>
inline
void
swap<int>(int& a, int&b) noexcept(is_nothrow_move_constructible<int>::value
                                  && is_nothrow_move_assignable<int>::value)
{
    test::__sort_stats.incr_count_swaps();
    using std::move;
    int temp(move(a));
    a = move(b);
    b = move(temp);
}
}
```

Comment: My guess is, your specialization is not used because it's not visible from `std::sort`'s body. The behavior might change if you move it before `#include <algorithm>`. Note however that templates in namespace `std` are only allowed to be specialized for user-defined types; otherwise, the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Personally, if I were to attempt this task, I'd not sort `int`s but instances of my own class, for which I could easily instrument `operator<` as well as copy- and move-constructors and assignment operators.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik. Ah, I think you are referring to _"It is allowed to add template specializations for any standard library template to the namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type..."_ at [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Adding_template_specializations). I will repeat my exercise with a custom type. Thanks!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - your suggestion worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**I was able to solve this following Igor's suggestion** about using a custom type (instead of `int`, which I was using earlier) and instrumenting the custom copy/move constructors/assignment operators. I also added an instrumented custom `swap()` function for the type, which simplified the `std::swap()` function template specialization.

Now, I get the following output:

```
std::sort(): Moves: 101606, Copies: 0, Swaps: 32821, Compares: 140451
std::stable_sort(): Moves: 129687, Copies: 0, Swaps: 0, Compares: 121474
```

If the move constructor/assignment-operators are not defined, the `Moves` counts above show up under `Copies`.

The following code works:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cassert>
#include<numeric>
#include<sstream>
#include<algorithm>

namespace test {

struct sort_stats {
    long long int __count_swaps;
    long long int __count_moves;
    long long int __count_copies;
    long long int __count_comps;

    void reset_stats()
    { __count_swaps = __count_moves = __count_copies = __count_comps = 0; }

    void incr_count_swaps()  { ++__count_swaps; }
    void incr_count_moves()  { ++__count_moves; }
    void incr_count_copies() { ++__count_copies; }
    void incr_count_comps()  { ++__count_comps; }

    std::string to_str() {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Moves: " << __count_moves
           << ", Copies: " << __count_copies
           << ", Swaps: " << __count_swaps
           << ", Compares: " << __count_comps;
        return ss.str();
    }
};

static sort_stats __sort_stats;

struct my_type
{
    int x;

    // default constructor
    my_type() = default;

    // copy constructor
    my_type(const my_type& other) : x (other.x)
    {
        __sort_stats.incr_count_copies();
    }

    // move constructor
    my_type(my_type&& other) noexcept : x (std::move(other.x))
    {
        __sort_stats.incr_count_moves();
    }

    // copy assignment operator
    my_type& operator=(const my_type& other)
    {
        __sort_stats.incr_count_copies();
        x = other.x;
        return *this;
    }

    // move assignment operator
    my_type& operator=(my_type&& other)
    {
        __sort_stats.incr_count_moves();
        x = std::move(other.x);
        return *this;
    }

    // '<' operator
    bool operator<(const my_type& other) const
    {
        __sort_stats.incr_count_comps();
        return x < other.x;
    }

    // swap 
    void swap(my_type& other)
    {
        __sort_stats.incr_count_swaps();
        my_type temp(std::move(*this));
        *this = std::move(other);
        other = std::move(temp);
    }

    // overload assignment operator for std::iota
    my_type& operator=(const int& val)
    {
        x = val;
        return *this;
    }

};

} // namespace test

namespace std {

using test::my_type;

// std::swap specialized for test::my_type
template<>
inline
void
swap<my_type>(my_type& a, my_type& b) noexcept(is_nothrow_move_constructible<my_type>::value
                                              && is_nothrow_move_assignable<my_type>::value)
{
    a.swap(b);
}
} // namespace std

using namespace test;

int main()
{
  const size_t SIZE = 10000;

  auto v = std::vector<my_type>(SIZE);
  std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);

  std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());
  std::cout << "std::sort(): ";
  __sort_stats.reset_stats();
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
  std::cout << __sort_stats.to_str() << "\n";
  assert(std::is_sorted(v.begin(), v.end()));

  std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());
  std::cout << "std::stable_sort(): ";
  __sort_stats.reset_stats();
  std::stable_sort(v.begin(), v.end());
  std::cout << __sort_stats.to_str() << "\n";
  assert(std::is_sorted(v.begin(), v.end()));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may overcount compares - you lump counts from `std::sort` and `std::is_sorted` together.

Comment: You're right. I'll need to swap the `assert` and `cout` statements. Thanks again.